# Terminal closes after entering a non-existing command

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, xterm

This seems to be a bug, but i'm not sure which package to report it on. Try this:

- Open gnome-terminal
- <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd> (open a new tab)
- type: `foo foo &`
- The tab is closed

Correct behavior would be `Command not found`.

This happens every time on gnome-terminal. On xterm (without tabs of course) it works randomly - maybe 2 of 3 times tried.

Comment: Which Ubuntu and kernel versions are you using? It works as it should for me.

Comment: I just tested this on another computer and it works as expected. I don't have a custom .bash_profile, and Ubuntu version is Saucy with updates. Looks like this issue is not easily reproducible.

Answer (score 6):

Let me guess, there is `set -e` (or it’s long form `set -o errexit`) option in your `.bashrc` (`.bash_profile`).

> **-e**
>
>
> Exit immediately if a *pipeline* (which may consist
> of a single *simple command*), a *subshell*
> command enclosed in parentheses, or one of the commands
> executed as part of a command list enclosed by braces (see
> **SHELL GRAMMAR** above) exits with a
> non-zero status. The shell does not exit if the command that
> fails is part of the command list immediately following a
> **while** or **until** keyword, part of the test
> following the **if** or **elif** reserved words, part
> of any command executed in a **&&** or **||**
> list except the command following the final
> **&&** or **||**, any command in a pipeline
> but the last, or if the command’s return value is
> being inverted with **!**. A trap on **ERR**, if set,
> is executed before the shell exits. This option applies to
> the shell environment and each subshell environment
> separately (see **COMMAND EXECUTION
> ENVIRONMENT** above), and may cause subshells to
> exit before executing all the commands in the subshell.

— bash(1)

This option is very useful for some scripts – it allows to avoid numerous `|| exit 1`, e. g. instead of

```
cd /var/ || exit 1
tar -cvf myarchive.tar "$SOMEDIR" || exit 1
rm -r "$SOMEDIR"
```

you can write

```
set -e
cd /var/
tar -cvf myarchive.tar "$SOMEDIR"
rm -r "$SOMEDIR"
```

But of course there is no any reason to set it for interactive bash session.

Comment: This is probably the right answer, but please explain in more detail.

Comment: See http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/seth.html for more information. `-e Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.`

Comment: @JohnWHSmith Thanks for the link. :) I'm suggesting the answer would be improved by providing more detail in the answer for the OP.

Comment: @chaskes Well. I don’t quite realize which details I may provide. Citation from man and example of proper usage perhaps (added)?

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov Yes, exactly. It's a much better answer now.

Answer (score 2):

Check and verify that you don't have some bashrc or profile configuration to change the normal behaviour of this instance.

The best way to verify this is to backup your current bashrc and profile files then replace the active ones with virgin copies of those two files.  Log out then log back in and check if you still have this behaviour.

If this cures this flaw, carefully add your custom configuration, and take note to the last change made if the flaw comes back.